# How do you launch docker from a another docker container-ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I have a Jenkins who run in an ubuntu docker-container. In order to dockerized by build, I need to also run docker in this container
My issue is that I don't understand how to start the daemon docker:

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

# this is a non-interactive automated build - avoid some warning 

messages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# update dpkg repositories
RUN apt-get update 

# install wget
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qqy \
apt-transport-https \
ca-certificates \
curl \
tar \
lxc \
iptables

# Install Docker from Docker Inc. repositories.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker.io

#install jenkins
```

...

```
 COPY jenkins.sh /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
 ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]
```

Comment: You should use official `docker:dind` image and pass the socket from the host folder `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` And you need it on jenkins slaves and not the main jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find,It was not:

```
   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker.io
```

but

```
   RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

No jenkinsSlave needed